# How can I add a registry key with MAUI app installation

Tags: registry, maui

I'm working on a windows app in .Net MAUI and I want to add the following registry key:

`HKEY_CLASSES_ROOT\*\shell\MyApp\command`

This is to create an "Open with MyApp" command in the Explorer context menu.

I have found the properties for file association in the `Platform/Windows/Package.appxmanifest` file but it does not allow a file type of `*`.

I know the registry can be updated in code when the app starts but it would require administrator privileges, when I don't expect the app to require administrator privileges to use.

If the app is published via the Microsoft app store, how can it add registry keys on install (and remove them on uninstall)?

Comment: You can check this [RegistryKey Class](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/microsoft.win32.registrykey?view=net-7.0).